# Schengen change of itinerary

Tags: schengen, europe, france

I have booked my flight to Paris for a 7 day stay, I’m thinking to stay 4 more day and extend my travel, my Visa is issued for 3 months and duration of stay is 30 days.
Can I extend my travel? Should I inform consular?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As long as you respect the limits given by the visa (start and end of validity, duration, number of entries) and do not deviate too much from your original plan (duration, countries visited, reason for the trip…) it shouldn’t be an issue.

For instance, if you had declared you wanted to visit Greece for 7 days for a conference, and instead travelled to France for one month for tourism, that would most likely raise quite a few questions. But extending your stay from 7 to 11 days should not. Plans change, and that’s why your visa was granted for a longer duration.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring public health restrictions relating to COVID-19, this is certainly within the rules. The consulate gave you some flexibility and you wish to take advantage of it.

You can certainly inform the consulate.  In fact, you might consider asking them whether it's permissible.  If you do this, you'll have a bit more peace of mind.  But it is not necessary, and the benefit of asking is probably small to non-existent.  The cost of asking is also small, however, so I would do it.  There's very little risk.